# Creating an objective c global class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, global, class-design

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple here, but can't find the answer though I looked in the other examples here, my code seems to be the same.
I'm trying to define a global class with some methods that I can access from the other classes in my project. I can define it, but can not access the methods from my other classes, though I always import the global class header to the class where I want to use the method. Heres the code:
 1st The Global class def:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalMethods : NSObject {}

- (unsigned long long)getMilliSeconds:(NSDate*)d;

- (NSDate *)getDateFromMs:(unsigned long long)ms;

@end

#import "GlobalMethods.h"

@implementation GlobalMethods

//SET DATE TO MILLISECONDS 1970 EPOCH

- (unsigned long long)getMilliSeconds:(NSDate*)d
{
    unsigned long long seconds = [d timeIntervalSince1970];

    unsigned long long milliSeconds = seconds * 1000;


    return milliSeconds;
}

// GET DATE FROM MILLISECONDS 1970 EPOCH

- (NSDate *)getDateFromMs:(unsigned long long)ms
{
    unsigned long long seconds = ms / 1000;
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970: seconds];

    return date;
}


@end

and then where I want to use my methods in another class:

#import "GlobalMethods.h"


// GET MILLISECONDS FROM 1970 FROM THE PICKER DATE
    NSDate *myDate = _requestDatePicker.date;

    milliSeconds = [self getMilliSeconds: myDate];
```

Error is : No visable interface for viewcontroller declares the selector getMilliSeconds.

Thanks for the help with this.

Comment: All classes are global. The term "global class" is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call the `getMilliSeconds:` method (which is an instance method of the `GlobalMethods` class) on an instance of your view controller class. That is the cause of the error.

As written you need to change this line:

```
milliSeconds = [self getMilliSeconds: myDate];
```

to:

```
GlobalMethods *global = [[GlobalMethods alloc] init];
milliSeconds = [global getMilliSeconds:myDate];
```

A better solution is to first change all of the instance methods of your `GlobalMethods` class to be class methods. In other words, in both the .h and .m file for `GlobalMethods`, change the leading `-` to a `+` for both methods.

Then in your view controller you can do:

```
milliSeconds = [GlobalMethods getMilliSeconds:myDate];
```

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, indeed the second is the better solution. Thanks for the learnings.